# Failed to create session

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, android-uiautomator

error : -

```
PS D:\rad\Appium> node test.js
2023-08-23T08:32:36.573Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
2023-08-23T08:32:36.575Z INFO @wdio/utils: Connecting to existing driver at http://localhost:4723/
2023-08-23T08:32:36.617Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
2023-08-23T08:32:36.617Z INFO webdriver: 
2023-08-23T08:32:36.641Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:4723
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
It seems like the service failed to start or is rejecting any connections.
```

command to start appium server : - `appium --base-path=/wd/hub`

command to run test.js :- `node test.js`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My team members decided to use Appium as the RPA tool for my assignment, and I'm facing the exact same issue as you, most of the documentation online is not updated.